# the distribution of triangles in a general $G(n,p)$ graph

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, graph-theory, random-graphs

let $Y$ be the random variable of the amount of triangles in a given graph.
what is the distribution of $Y$?
I tried looking at the probability of $I_{i,j,k}$ the indicator of 3 given nodes having a triangle, and I came to a conclusion that $P(I_{i,j,k}=1) = p^3$. but each $I_{i,j,k}$ depends on its neighboring nodes indicators, so it can not be binomial.
thank you!

Comment: The tag *[distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)* is *not* about *[probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions)*.

Comment: What do we know about the nodes and edges in the graph?

Comment: The actual distribution is messy and complicated and cannot be what you are looking for. You might want the expected value, the limiting distribution as $n \to \infty$, or other things which can all be found with a casual search for "triangles" in the [tag:random-graphs] tag.